# ruby on rails parse string and output the result into an existing table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string

I have a text which contains names, each name is written between 2 apostrophes.
For example:

```
'James' is the best player we had since 'Jane' left
```

I need to extract all those names from the text and insert them into one of the columns in my database.
I'm new with Rails, and I was wondering how it will be best to parse this text.

Comment: Use a regular expression

Comment: Do any of the names have apostrophes inside them, e.g. `'O'Keefe'`?

Comment: No, we can assume none of the names have apostrophes inside them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"'James' is the best player we had since 'Jane' left".scan(/\'(\w+)\'/).flatten 
#=> ["James", "Jane"]
```

Comment: It's an edge case but worth noting that this will fail if a name has any non-word characters in it, notably spaces e.g. `'Mary Jo'`.